# glog symbols different in different machines

Tags: c++, bazel

I'm using bazel to import third-party libraries, which includes glog.
The workspace looks like

```
def glog_workspace():
    http_archive(
        name = "com_google_glog",
        sha256 = "8a83bf982f37bb70825df71a9709fa90ea9f4447fb3c099e1d720a439d88bad6",
        strip_prefix = "glog-0.6.0/",
        urls = ["https://github.com/google/glog/archive/v0.6.0.tar.gz"],
    )
```

I tried to use an internal function to get stacktrace in human-readable format.

```
google::glog_internal_namespace_::DumpStackTraceToString(std::string);
```

I check the glog library in two machines, both ubuntu.
First machine

```
$ uname -a
Linux <hostname> 5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 11:14:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Second machine

```
$ uname -a
Linux <hostname> 5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 11:14:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

In the first machine, it contains the symbol I need.

```
$ nm -C bazel-out//k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_google_glog/libglog.so  | grep Dump
000000000002c350 t google::(anonymous namespace)::DumpTimeInfo()
000000000002c600 t google::(anonymous namespace)::DumpSignalInfo(int, siginfo_t*)
000000000002c490 t google::(anonymous namespace)::DumpStackFrameInfo(char const*, void*)
000000000002f070 T google::glog_internal_namespace_::DumpStackTraceToString(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)
000000000002f0a0 t google::DumpStackTrace(int, void (*)(char const*, void*), void*)
000000000002f670 t google::DumpPCAndSymbol(void (*)(char const*, void*), void*, void*, char const*)
000000000002f350 t google::DumpStackTraceAndExit()
000000000002f770 t google::DumpPC(void (*)(char const*, void*), void*, void*, char const*)
```

But it doesn't exist in second machine, thus failing the linker.

```
$ nm -C bazel-out//k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_google_glog/libglog.so  | grep Dump
0000000000022fc0 t google::(anonymous namespace)::DumpTimeInfo()
0000000000023110 t google::(anonymous namespace)::DumpStackFrameInfo(char const*, void*)
```

I'm wondering, why would this happen?

Update:
I did some hacking to explicitly enable these functions.
But another thing confuses me:

```
ubuntu@hao:~/ghost-playground$ bazel build //base:logging_test 
INFO: Writing tracer profile to '/home/ubuntu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ubuntu/212e06aedd435bfcd4b0defa3d42f92f/command.profile.gz'
INFO: Analyzed target //base:logging_test (0 packages loaded, 5 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /home/ubuntu/ghost-playground/base/BUILD:28:1: Linking of rule '//base:logging_test' failed (Exit 1) clang failed: error executing command /usr/bin/clang @bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/base/logging_test-2.params

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/_solib_k8/libbase_Sliblogging.so: error: undefined reference to 'google::glog_internal_namespace_::DumpStackTraceToString(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Target //base:logging_test failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.255s, Critical Path: 0.08s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully

ubuntu@hao:~/ghost-playground$ nm -C bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/external/com_google_glog/libglog.so | grep DumpStackTraceToString
0000000000026230 t google::glog_internal_namespace_::DumpStackTraceToString(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)
```

According to the symbol displayed, `DumpStackTraceToString` does exist, and is valid (not 'U' which means undefined).

Comment: Without having verified: these are different Ubuntu distributions? And you are using the `bazel` autodetected compiler toolchain? So maybe `bazel` detects different versions of `gcc` on these different Ubuntu distributions that come with different standard flags? But that is quite a stretch.

Alternative: maybe `glog` internally `#ifdef`s some compiler defines to find out the C++ version which with you compile and your different compiler versions default to different C++ versions.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-ups!
> these are different Ubuntu distributions?
No, As you could see above, both are ubuntu.
> And you are using the bazel autodetected compiler toolchain? 
First no, second yes. And both are using clang. I'm confused why compiler/linker version would make a difference to the symbols generated?
> maybe glog internally #ifdefs some compiler defines
That's a good suggestion! Let me take a deeper look! Really thank you!

Comment: Are they the same version of Ubuntu? Where did these glog shared libraries come from?

Comment: > Are they the same version of Ubuntu?
No.
> Where did these glog shared libraries come from?
I found them both at `bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/_solib_k8/libexternal_Scom_Ugoogle_Uglog_Slibglog.so`.

Comment: One thing I found weird is: on the first machine which works, there're both static and dynamic libraries; but on the second machine which doesn't work, there's only dynamic library.

Comment: And on the machine which doesn't work, the stacktrace symbols hows undefined.
```
U google::GetStackTrace(void**, int, int)
```

Comment: Hi @AlanBirtles I made some updates on the question description.

Comment: Hi @lummax I made some updates on the question description.